# Ruby on Rails install trouble on OSX with dependencies

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install RoR on Mountain Lion. I have the following installed:

- Xcode from the App Store with command line tools
- RVM
- homebrew

In terminal I verified that gcc is installed.

When I type in `"rvm requirements"` I get a message saying that I'm missing a number of dependencies including `OpenSSL`, `autoconf`, `automake`, `libxslt` and many more. `RVM` also says to install these with `brew`. So I do and `rvm` no longer complains about the missing dependencies.

But when I try to install `ruby 1.9.3` via `"rvm install 1.9.3"`, at the end of the compile I receive a message `"ruby was built using clang -but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors."`

I'm stumped at this point. I'm trying to figure out:

1. Why are dependencies missing when I've installed `Xcode` command line tools?
2. Why am I still getting a compile error after using brew to install the dependencies?

Help please. :)

Comment: Looking at the RVM GitHub repo there's a thread regarding such a problem with Xcode 4.6:

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1480

Comment: I don't see any dependency errors or compile errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **gcc** compiler instead i.e

**`rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc-4.2`**

Reference: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1480

Comment: Didn't fix it. That line was incorrect according to the reply one of the Engine Yard guys offered up: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1480#issuecomment-13032972

Comment: Compiling it with the proper syntax resolved it: "rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2". Just not clear why I had to specify that flag when I had used brew to install apple-gcc42. Config issue?

Answer (score 0):

So here's the order I usually go through before installing any Rubies.

**1st thing:** Install XCode and the [Command Line Tools for Mountain Lion](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (you can also install these from the Preferences > Downloads window).

**2nd:** Make sure you have [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/) installed.

**3rd:** Once that's set up, run `brew tap homebrew/dupes`

**4th:** Then `brew install openssl autoconf apple-gcc42 automake`

I had issues with RVM and have long since switched to [RBenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)/[Ruby-Build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build). There are various differences, but really running through the above steps should fix any issues you had, and lots of people use one or the other. Both are great.

Then, just try to install Ruby however you choose to.

Comment: No dice Kevin. Appreciate the effort. Hope I can get some help on it.